# Prototype getValue of an input to var, when click and element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype

I have a problem getting the value of a DOM element by clicking. The element has the 'class' attribute set. My code looks like this.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
   $$('.sepetle').invoke('observe', 'click', function(element){
        var giftDetailID = element.down('input.gldID').getValue();

    });
});
```

Here I am trying to get input's value which has class .gldID by clicking a.sepetle. My inputs are inside the 'a' elements

```
     <tr id="<?=$row->GLD_ID?>">            
        <td><?=$row->ProdName?></td>
        <td><?=$row->ProdPrice?></td>                                 
        <td>
            <a class="sepetle" onclick="SepeteEkleDayi('<?=$row->ProdID?>');" href="javascript:;">Sepete At</a>
            <input class="gldID" type="hidden" value="<?=$row->GLD_ID?>" />                      
        </td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `down()` method goes "down" the DOM child chain - in this instance `<a>` and `<input>` are siblings, so `<input>` would not be down from the `<a>`. You can approach this a few ways depending on what else you plan on putting in these table cells.

If it is only the `<a>` and the `<input>` then this will work

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
   $$('.sepetle').invoke('observe', 'click', function(element){
        var giftDetailID = element.siblings()[0].getValue();
    });
});
```

Otherwise I would do this which is more flexible

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
   $$('.sepetle').invoke('observe', 'click', function(element){
        var giftDetailID = element.up('td').down('input.gldID').getValue();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also `next()` which might be useful here. Also the `on()` function if you're using 1.7. (The point of using `on` is that you only create one listener for the whole page, not one per element.)

```
document.on('click', '.sepetle', function(evt, elm){
  evt.stop();
  var giftDetailId = $F(elm.next('input'));

});
```

Event.stop(evt) will stop the click from happening, so you don't need to use `javascript:;` URLs in your HTML. It's better form to provide an actual URL that will replicate the JS output, rather than these un-crawlable fake URLs. (Unless, of course, you are doing something destructive with the click, like a DELETE.)

You also don't need the document.observe('dom:loaded') wrapper around `on()` -- another win!